# Geoprocessing tool default path access every one?

Tags: arcpy

I am using Geoprocessing tools i have face one problem with default gdb access in my system (default gdb means C:\Documents and Settings\\My Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb ) how can access different users same default gdb file. Example my user is schalla it is working fine same tool use another person it is getting error message like attachment

Comment: You question mentions an attachment but SE does not support attachments.  Would you be able to **edit** your question to include the text from your error message instead, please?

Answer (score 3):

You are better off using the scratchGDB workspace. Esri guarantees this path to exist for any user.

```
import arcpy
import os

GDB = arcpy.env.scratchGDB
output = os.path.join(GDB, "FeatureClass")
```

This method uses the default path to the scratch workspace environment which removes the need to know a specific file path. You can look [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Scratch_GDB/001w00000047000000/) for other ways to use the workspace.

Comment: Hi could you please give me any idea for above question because tool working in my login only in case run in another user it is not running

Answer (score 2):

If you want your users to be able to run your tool from ArcGIS application (such as ArcMap) and write output data into a known location, you should use `arcpy.env.workspace` in your code.

For you it will be `C:\\Users\\schalla\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb`. Test yourself running `arcpy.env.workspace` from Python window in ArcMap.

```
import os
...
outputFc = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace,"OutputResult")
```

This will make sure output dataset will be written to a default geodatabase that user running ArcMap has.

Comment: Alex could you please look once attached snap